# Can I Have Unnamed Dynamic Array Types as Var Parameters

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010

Using D2010, I'd like to do something like this:

```
procedure SizeArray(var aArr: array of integer; aSize: integer);
begin
  SetLength(aArr,aSize);
end;
```

But this fails to compile. Because my "aArr" parameter isn't a dynamic array, it's an open array parameter. And SetLength cannot be called on it. The only way I know of to force the parameter to be a dynamic array is to give it a type name, like so:

```
type
  TIntArray = array of integer;

procedure SizeArray(var aArr: TIntArray; aSize: integer);
begin
  SetLength(aArr,aSize);
end;
```

And now the code compiles. And it works fine, for the most part, but this fails:

```
procedure Test;
var
  a : array of integer;
begin
  SizeArray(a,5);
end;
```

Because types of actual and formal var parameters must be identical and the compiler doesn't recognize "array of integer" and "TIntArray" as identical types.

So, here's my question: Is there some way I can get the compiler to identify my var parameter as a dynamic array rather than as an open array so that the caller can declare a simple "array of integer" rather than some named type?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you want/need to? This is standard Pascal usage. All you need to do is declare "a" as a: TIntArray. If you are working on legacy code, you need to make changes to it anyway (to add call to SizeArray)
I assume that SizeArray is just a sample - otherwise why not call SetLength directly>

Comment: Forcing the caller to use the named type works, but it's not my preference. I'd like something that doesn't require that and can accept simple "array of X" types. So I thought I'd ask and find out if it can be done.

Comment: It's really no big deal for the caller to use the right type. You do that all the time with record and class types, so why not other structured types? And it's a requirement the programmer will discover very quickly since the code won't compile otherwise, so it's not like you're putting in some ticking time bomb that won't go off until the product's just about ready to ship. Just be sure to use the type provided by the RTL, if there is one, instead of making up your own declaration.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Pascal, and by extension Delphi, uses name equivalence rather than structural equivalence for array types, including dynamic arrays. Variables declared with a type that doesn't have a name, like this:

```
var
  x: array of Integer;
```

... end up using an anonymous name that isn't equivalent to any other type's name. That's why you get the error. The error can be useful; for example, consider an array of `Kilometers` vs an array of `Kilograms` - but it's often the case that declaring a name for every distinct type is inconvenient.

To get around this issue, and staying within the safe type system (so avoiding untyped parameters, as skamradt suggests), I recommend using the same name for every particular array shape. You can do this to a reasonably large degree by using the `TArray<T>` type declared in the System unit. So, instead of working with `array of Integer`, use `TArray<Integer>`.

`TArray<T>` is declared like this:

```
type
  TArray<T> = array of T;
```

... so it can supply a name for arbitrary dynamic arrays.

Comment: I hadn't noticed the declaration in System. That's nice. I think getting into the habit of declaring my arrays this way will be useful. 

At first I thought the TArray in System conflicted with the one in Generics.Collections, but I guess it doesn't since that one isn't a generic. This is a nice solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 9):

This is indeed possible...just use the absolute keyword along with an untyped var.

```
procedure SizeArray(var aArr; aSize: integer);
var
  ActArr : Array of Integer absolute aArr;
begin
  SetLength(ActArr,aSize);
end;

var
  Test : Array of Integer;
begin
  SizeArray(Test,5);
  showMessage(IntTostr(High(Test)));  // -- returns 4
end;
```

Comment: +1 for extreme cleverness. I've already started down Barry Kelly's path, so I'm accepting his answer. But, for finding a way... I'm impressed. :)

Answer (score 0):

No, there's no way to do that.  It's part of the Pascal language specification and isn't likely to change.

EDIT:  Skamradt found a way.  Let me restate that.  There's no way to do that *safely.*

Comment: Ah, but programming without rails adds a bit of adrenaline to the mix.  ... oh, wait, that was the jolt cola from the last round of all night debugging.  :)

Comment: I program without rails all the time.  Never been a big fan of Ruby, to be honest... ;)